# Check if text contains sequence. Adjacency of the characters is not required

Tags: javascript, string, contains

I am trying to make a function that will answer true if the sequence is present and false if it isn't. This is different though from normal check if string contains substring because adjacency of the characters isn't required. For example in a string "Lord Of The Rings" the substring "LOTR" or "other" should return true since they can be found in the string. Using the typical

```js
function contains(text, sequence) {
if (text.indexOf(sequence)  !== -1){
    return true;
}
return false;
}

console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lord")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lens")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "other")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "l o t r")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "Lord")); // False
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "orks")); // False
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "z")); // False
```

doesn't work and it will return false on "LOTR" or "something", above  are some examples I am working with

Thank you!

Comment: Does the sequence need to be in the correct order?

Comment: Yes it does, for example in "lord of the rings" the sequence rtol should return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Boring (But Effective) For-Loop Method:

Edited to terminate the loop ASAP when the result is known; for example, when there are more characters remaining in the sequence than in the text.

```js
function contains(text, sequence) {
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length && j < sequence.length; i++) {
    if (text.length - i < sequence.length - j) return false
    if (text[i] === sequence[j]) j++
  }
  return j === sequence.length
}


console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lord")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lens")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "other")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "l o t r")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "Lord")); // False
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "orks")); // False
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "z")); // False
```

Comment: An upvote and accept would always be appreciated if you have the time :) I also edited the function to be slightly more performant if you'd like to copy the new version instead.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's just that it's my first question didn't know how to do that XD. Thanks again! I actually expected a way more complicated answer and was surprized when it was actually pretty simple, I was just thinking in the other direction when solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the `sequence` into a regex and check if the text match. Like this:

```js
function contains(text, sequence) {
  if(!sequence.length) return true;                       // if sequence is empty return true
  
  var regex = new RegExp(sequence.split('').join('.*'));  // generate the regex

  return regex.test(text);                                // return whether the text matches or not
}

console.log(contains("lord of the rings", ""));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lord"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lens"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "other"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "l o t r"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "Lord"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "orks"));
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "z"));
```

If the `sequence` is for example `'txt'` the the generated egex will be `/t.*x.*t/` that will match the characters `t`, `x` and `t` in that order separated by any number of characters (0 or more).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `sequence` to a case-insensitive regular expression in the form:

```
/L.*O.*T.*R/i
```

...where `.*` matches zero or more of any character:

```js
function contains(text, sequence) {
  return (new RegExp(
            sequence.split("")
                    .map( (c) => c.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') )
                    .join(".*"),
            "i")
         ).test(text)
}

console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lord")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "lens")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "other")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "l o t r")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "Lord")); // True
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "orks")); // False
console.log(contains("lord of the rings", "z")); // False
console.log(contains("Hi. How are you?", "i.?")); // True
```

The ugly `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` part is to escape any characters in the input that have special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Set`, if the order of the sequence doesn't matter . The time complexity is O(n+m), linear to the length of text plus sequence's.

Store the characters in the `Set`, and use `set.has(value)` to check.

```
function contains(text, sequence) {
  var s = new Set();
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      s.add(text[i]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
     if(!s.has(sequence[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```